# Create macro to simplify declaration of deeply nested enum?

Tags: rust, enums

I want to use deeply nested enums to represent blocks in my game:

```rust
enum Element { Void, Materal(Material) }
enum Material { Gas(Gas), NonGas(NonGas) }
enum NonGas { Liquid(Liquid), Solid(Solid) }
enum Solid { MovableSolid(MovableSolid), ImmovableSolid(ImmovableSolid) }
enum Gas { Smoke }
enum Liquid { Water }
enum ImmovableSolid { Bedrock }
enum MovableSolid { Sand, GunPowder }
```

I found it very verbose to declare an `Element`:

```rust
let block: Element = Element::Materal(Material::NonGas(NonGas::Solid(Solid::ImmovableSolid(ImmovableSolid::Bedrock))));
```

Is it possible to create a macro to add syntactic sugar for my enum declaration?

I'm hoping to create a macro that can automagically resolve the enum path, for example

```rust
let block: Element = NewElement!(ImmovableSolid::Bedrock);
```

Comment: You could have `Element` implement `From<Material>`, `From<Solid>`, etc., and then you'd be able to do `ImmovableSolid::Bedrock.into()`. As an aside, the `NonGas` type is a bit weird. Shouldn't it just be `enum Material { Gas(Gas), Liquid(Liquid), Solid(Solid) }`?.

Comment: ahh implementing `From<>` sounds promising (not aware of this function before). Also I realized `NonGas` was bad idea... I was thinking `Liquid` and `Solid` can exhibit simliar behavior such as affected by gravity... Now I realize in the `match` syntax I can use the or pattern `Solid | Liquid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cdhowie's `From` idea, I think you'd only need trait impls from your lowest level enums. You can skip ones like `impl From<Material> for Element` because you need a child to create a `Material`, so it doesn't really make sense to start at that level.

```rust
impl From<Gas> for Element {
    fn from(e: Gas) -> Element {
        Element::Materal(Material::Gas(e))
    }
}

impl From<Liquid> for Element {
    fn from(e: Liquid) -> Element {
        Element::Materal(Material::NonGas(NonGas::Liquid(e)))
    }
}

impl From<ImmovableSolid> for Element {
    fn from(e: ImmovableSolid) -> Element {
        Element::Materal(Material::NonGas(NonGas::Solid(Solid::ImmovableSolid(e))))
    }
}

impl From<MovableSolid> for Element {
    fn from(e: MovableSolid) -> Element {
        Element::Materal(Material::NonGas(NonGas::Solid(Solid::MovableSolid(e))))
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Element::from(ImmovableSolid::Bedrock));
}
```